# BxSlider in React.JS component

Tags: jquery, reactjs, import, bxslider

I am trying to run bxSlider in a React Component. Have installed `jQuery` in the project imported jQuery in the App.js file. `import $ from 'jquery'`.
Followed [this](https://bxslider.com/install/) for installing bxSlider via npm.

Step-1 ) Added following lines in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="/node_modules/bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```

Step-2) Added following lines in App.js `render()`

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="/images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Step-3) Added following lines in App.js `componentDidMount()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

Error being displayed:

```
TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default(...)(...).bxSlider is not a function
```

Please advice what I am missing here.
I have also tried importing directly then shows `jquery` is not defined:

`import '../../../node_modules/bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I succeeded to make it work in my app, but struggle to show you in a code sandbox

I just added this in my `index.html`

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slider').bxSlider()
      })
    </script>
```

and this code in my `App.js`

```
      <div className="slider">
        <div>I am a slide.</div>
        <div>I am another slide.</div>
      </div>
```

and I make it works, another solution will be to use `react-slick` instead